Threshold selection in chain classifier
Imagine a set of $m$ classifiers and $N$ precedents, each assigned a threshold $\theta_{i,j}$, meaning, if threshold $t_j$ on classifier $j$ for precedent $i$ is bigger than $\theta_{i,j}$, the precedent passes the classifier: $t_j>\theta_{i,j}$
If precedent passes a classifier, it comes into the next classifier. After passing all classifiers, the precedent marked as $+$, if precedent is discarded by at least 1 classifier in chain, it's marked as $-$.
The question is, how to pick thresholds $t_i$, for each of $m$ classifiers, such that true positive rate is maximized, while false positive rate is below some $T$?
I tried searching the internet for threshold selection algorithms, common machine learning libraries and formulating the problem as mixed integer problem to be solved by some solver, alas, without success (currently pending on Math Stackexchange)

Can be solved by solving a mixed integer programming problem described on this Math Stackexchange answer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
